# Pipe multiple files to one response

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe

I'm trying to write two files and some more text to a response.
The code below does however only return the first file and the "Thats all!" text.

```
var http = require('http'),
    util = require('util'),
    fs   = require('fs');

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){  
    var stream  = fs.createReadStream('one.html'),
        stream2 = fs.createReadStream('two.html');

    stream.on('end', function(){
        stream2.pipe(res, { end:false});
    });

    stream2.on('end', function(){
        res.end("Thats all!");
    });

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
    stream.pipe(res, { end:false});

}).listen(8001);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Duplex stream, which will pass the data from one stream to another.

```
stream.pipe(duplexStream).pipe(stream2).pipe(res);
```

In the example above the first pipe will write all data from `stream` to `duplexStream` then there will be data written from the `duplexStream` to the `stream2` and finally `stream2` will write your data to the `res` writable stream.

This is an example of one possible implementation of the write method.

```
DuplexStream.write = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
   this.push(chunk);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **stream-stream** It's a pretty basic node module (using no dependencies)

```
var ss = require('stream-stream');
var fs = require('fs');

var files = ['one.html', 'two.html'];
var stream = ss();

files.forEach(function(f) {
    stream.write(fs.createReadStream(f));
});
stream.end();

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
stream.pipe(res, { end:false});
```